# How to find stack size?

Tags: c, stack

I am having little experience in C programming.  I want to find **stack size of particular function without running the executable**. I am using **gcc** compiler.

Is there any way to do this ? Please share your tips.

Comment: I'm not even sure "stack size" is a concept that exists without execution :)

Comment: sure, a system (in that case, your compiler, and OS combination) might have a default stack frame size, but how much is actually used would usually be up to the execution

Answer (score 2):

Use `gdb` `info frame` command to get information about a stack frame.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Frame-Info.html

With the the address of the frame and the address of the next frame up, you will be able to know the size of a frame.

Comment: Without running the executable, i want to get the stack size. Is it possible?

Comment: Without running the executable and without modifying your program, what you can do is to assembly dump the function (e.g., using objdump -S).

Comment: #objdum -S foo.o

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq

How to get the exact size for stack from this dump.